# Deduce non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-argument-deduction

Is it possible to deduce a non-type template parameter from a template function parameter?

Consider this simple template:

```
template <int N> constexpr int factorial()
{
        return N * factorial<N - 1>();
}

template <> constexpr int factorial<0>()
{
        return 1;
}

template <> constexpr int factorial<1>()
{
        return 1;
}
```

I would like to be able to change `factorial` so that I can alternatively call it like this:

```
factorial(5);
```

and let the compiler figure out the value of N at compile time.
Is this possible? Maybe with some fancy C++11 addition?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The `factorial` function doesn't accept any parameters. What's the benefit of `factorial(5)` over the correct `factorial<5>()`?

Comment: @CodyGray: I think that the idea would be to create a generic `factorial` function able to calculate the result at compile time if it's given a compile-time-known expression, but also able to calculate it at runtime if the input is a normal variable.

Comment: @Matteo: So far as I understand, nothing is being calculated at runtime since the expression is declared `constexpr`. And anyway, I don't understand why there'd be any problem passing a "normal variable" instead of the 5 using the standard syntax. The question here is "how can I avoid typing angle brackets", and I don't understand the motivation.

Comment: I want to avoid having to change lots of code. Also, I find it to be more idiomatic, but that's something I can easily pass on ;)

Comment: @CodyGray: `constexpr` works just like @Matteo said: if all arguments in a `constexpr` function call are compile-time constants, the call will be evaluated at compile time, otherwise, it's executed at runtime like any other function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can't be done, unless you have a time machine.

The parameter to the function is handled at runtime. Yes, in *your* case it's a literal constant, but that's a special case.

In function definitions, the parameter *types* are fixed at compile-time (and thus, can be used to deduce template parameters), but parameter *values* are only fixed at runtime.

Why do you need this? Is it just so you don't have to type the `<>`'s?

Comment: Pretty much, I have a huge code base with calls to several functions which I rewrote as a template. Replacing the names is trivial, but turning all `f(2, 3, "abc", true)` into `f<2, 3, true>("abc")` is a little bit trickier.

Comment: How about a macro to convert `f(2, 3, "abc", true)` into `f_impl<2, 3, true>("abc")`?

Answer (score 9):

Your current code would normally be written as follows, I believe:

```
constexpr factorial (int n)
{
    return n > 0 ? n * factorial( n - 1 ) : 1;
}
```

If you call it with a constant-expression, such as `factorial(5)`, then all the compiler magic will come into play. But if you do `int a = 3; factorial(a)`, then I think it will fall back on a conventional function - i.e. it won't have built a lookup table of pre-computed answers.

In general, you should mark every function and constructor as `constexpr` if you can. You lose nothing, the compiler will treat it as a normal function if necessary.

Comment: I didn't know constexpr works opt-out like that. Sadly, the code is just an example and I need a fixed-size array inside the actual function, so I need a template with the array size as a parameter.

Comment: Perhaps build an array of function pointers to the templated functions at compile time, and look them up at runtime? `factorial[3](.. other args ..)`

Comment: @pezcode: change factorial to a macro that calls the template code, Aaron: youd be better of building an array of the results

Comment: @MooingDuck, yep, but see pezcode's comment on this answer - I think the real application is more complicated than this. I get the impression that some args are to be these templated-ints, whereas their may be other parameters also.

Comment: If you can mark every function and constructor as `constexpr` without any negative consequences, it (again) raises the question of why this isn't the default for C++11 compilers... I guess it's the sacred back-compat problem again.

Comment: I'm no expert @CodyGray, but I think the only downside with default constexpr for everything is that the compilation might be much slower or perhaps even be stuck in an infinite loop. *PS:* And maybe there are some compatibility issues as you say, certain software might assume they're dealing with 'real' functions.

Comment: A function marked as `constexpr` is limited in what you can do inside of it to limit the burden on compiler-writers to be able to compute it at compile time. You mark functions with `constexpr` to tell the compiler that it should complain if you don't meet those restrictions so that your code will be portable to other compilers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that; the only way you could do that would be having a `constexpr` function parameter that would be passed then as the `template` parameter for the template version of `factorial`, but `constexpr` function parameters are not admitted.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that. Template arguments can only be deduced from the *type* of function argument, not the *value*, which will not in general be known at compile time.

Of course, you could rewrite `factorial` as a non-template `constexpr` function; then it would be evaluated at compile time if the argument is known then.

Answer (score 1):

Use an evil macro:

```
#define factorial(X) factorial<X>()
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible, unless you want to create a huge switch statement :

```
int getFactorial( const int v )
{
  switch ( v )
  {
    case 1 : return factorial<1>();
    case 2 : return factorial<2>();
    //etc
    default:
       ;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround solution for this kind of problem is to utilize some `struct` like this:

```
template <int X>
struct constant {
    operator int () { return X; }
};
```

Then we can have overload on `constant<X>` like this:

```
template <int X>
void f (constant<X>)
```

Utilizing value of `X` at compile-time and runtime overloads `f (int)`. The annoying part is that it requires some discipline on the call site since every literal constant has to be wrapped as `constant<X> {}` (with macro or something like this).