# Using non-type template template parameter in template specialisation

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-templates, non-type

I am learning about template metaprogramming and I have hit a snag trying to achieve something
which I think should be possible, I just quite can't figure out how to do it.

I found these two answers that I thought were somewhat related but didn't really help

- [Extract C++ template
  parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301203/extract-c-template-parameters)
- [Deduce non-type template
  parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837113/deduce-non-type-template-parameter)

Let's say I want to represent points in 1D and 2D space, then I can define these as follows:

```
template <int X>
struct Point1D {
    static constexpr int x = X;
};

template <int X, int Y>
struct Point2D {
    static constexpr int x = X;
    static constexpr int y = Y;
};
```

Now I want to calculate the distance between two points. One option is to do this:

```
template <typename Point1, typename Point2>
struct Distance {
    static constexpr int value = Point2::x - Point1::x;
};

typedef Distance<Point1D<1>, Point1D<5>> dist;
dist::value; //4
```

However this will accept both Point2D and ANY type that defines ::x

```
template <int X>
struct RandomType {
    static constexpr int x = X;
};

typedef Distance<Point2D<5, 4>, Point1D<2>> dist2; //Should not work
typedef Distance<Point1D<5>, RandomType<6>> dist3; //Should not work either
```

Now, it should be possible to specialise Distance for Point1D and Point2D types, however this is where I get stuck. I tried the following:

```
template <template <int...> typename Point1, template <int...> typename Point2>
struct Distance {};

template <>
struct Distance<Point1D, Point1D> {
    /* Calculate distance between two points */
};

template <>
struct Distance<Point2D, Point2D> {
    /* Calculate distance between two points in 2D space */
};
```

But of course now I am specialising for a class template, not a type, so this won't work. I can pass the non-type parameters to the specialisation as such:

```
template <template <int...> typename Point1, int N, 
          template <int...> typename Point2, int M>
struct Distance {};

template <int N, int M>
struct Distance<Point1D, N, Point1D, M> {
    static constexpr int value = Point1D<M>::x - Point1D<N>::x;
};

typedef Distance<Point1D, 2, Point1D, 5> Two;
int x = Two::value; //3
```

But this defeats the purpose as I could just pass 5 and 2 for the distance. What I really need to do is able to pass any class template that takes one int N and has a member X so that I can call Distance with any `Point1D<N>`. E.g. something like this:

```
typedef Point1D<4> p1;
typedef Point1D<6> p2;
Distance<p1, p2>::value; //2

typedef Point2D<4, 6> p3;
Distance<p3, p1>::value //Error, can't mix Point1D and Point2D

/* Something of the sort (doesn't compile) */
template<int N, int M>
struct Distance<Point1D<N>, Point1D<M>> {
    static constexpr int value = Point1D<N>::x - Point1D<M>::x;
};
```

Conceptually I think this should work since at the point of the call to Distance the type contains all the information needed. Somehow, by specifying that Distance takes a template `Point1D<int N>` I need the function to be able to call `Point1D<N>::x`. The syntax is what I am unable to figure out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the solution is to declare the template type `Distance` but not define it, and only partially specialize for each acceptable pair of types.  For example:

```
template <typename, typename>
struct Distance;
```

Since there is no definition for this template type, attempting to instantiate it with arbitrary types will fail, except when the type arguments match a partial specialization defined later.

Now partially specialize for `Point1D`:

```
template <int ...A, int ...B>
struct Distance<Point1D<A...>, Point1D<B...>> {
    static constexpr int value = Point1D<B...>::x - Point1D<A...>::x;
};
```

You can partially specialize this for `Point2D` by using the same technique and changing the calculation as desired:

```
template <int ...A, int ...B>
struct Distance<Point2D<A...>, Point2D<B...>> {
    static constexpr int value = /* ... */;
};
```

---

(Note that the int parameter packs are technically unnecessary since you know how many parameters each type uses. However, using packs keeps the partial specialization definitions consistent with each other *and* makes the code simpler to maintain. It also enforces that the calculation uses the values `Point_D<...>::x` instead of just using the value of the template argument.)

Answer (score 1):

> What I really need to do is able to pass any class template that takes
>   one int N and has a member X

Why, your last attempt is good:

```
// Declare `Distance` as a template that takes two type parameters.
template <typename A, typename B>
struct Distance;

// Specialize 'Distance' for a special case where both type parameters
// are instances of the same template class.
template <template <int> typename AnyTemplate, int N, int M>
struct Distance<AnyTemplate<N>, AnyTemplate<M>>
{
    static constexpr int value = AnyTemplate<N>::x - AnyTemplate<M>::x;
};
```